# Remove beforeClose event handler - jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, noty

I have a jQuery UI dialog box with a form inside it. I'm trying to implement a feature where if a field in the form has been modified, we'll be showing a confirmation message using [noty](http://ned.im/noty/)

Now, unlike an javaScript confirmation box, noty does not stop script execution. So, in the dialog `beforeClose` event, I'm -

Showing a noty confirmation if form data **is modified** and then returning false.
Simply returning true if the form data **has not been modified**.

All is working well. Now we ask the user -

The data in the form has been modified. Are you sure you want to close?

If he clicks **no** - we simply close the noty and keep the dialog box open.
But if he clicks **yes**, we try to close the dialog box, which triggers the `beforeClose` event handler again and we go into the loop again.

I've tried calling `.off` on the `div` that has been converted to a dialog box before calling the close event, but that doesn't seem to be removing the click.

Here is a simple pseudo code to explain the issue -

```
DialogCloseEvent() {
    if data has been modified { 
        Show noty {
            // IMPORTANT - This is executed after return false.
            in noty user clicks NO - do not close dialog box {
                close noty and done
            } 
            in noty user clicks YES - close the dialog box {
                // This calls the DialogCloseEvent again.   
                call the close method of the dialog box.            
                close noty
            }
        }
        return false
    }   
    no it has not been modifed {
        // Closes the dialog without calling the event again
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on your pseudo code you could add a flag to force close the dialog:

```
var forceClose = false;

DialogCloseEvent() {
    if data has been modified and !forceClose  { 
        Show noty {
            // IMPORTANT - This is executed after return false.
            in noty user clicks NO - do not close dialog box {
                close noty and done
            } 
            in noty user clicks YES{ 

                forceClose = true;

                - close the dialog box {
                    // This calls the DialogCloseEvent again.   
                    call the close method of the dialog box.            
                    close noty
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }   
    no it has not been modifed {
        // Closes the dialog without calling the event again
        return true;
    }
}
```

UPDATE with code

```
var forceClose = false;

$("#dialog").dialog({
    open: function (event, ui) {
        forceClose = false; //reset the flag each time
    },
    beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
        if(forceClose){
            return true;
        }

        //your dialog close event
        //set the flag to true when you want to close the jqueryui dialog

    }
});
```

Comment: This is a problem because we can't think of an alternate way to close the dialog, without triggering the close event.

Comment: Since this noty dialog doesn't block the execution like confirm(), I think this approach is better than unbinding/binding event handlers. But it's possible to unbind the beforeClose handler before closing the noty...

Comment: The approach is good and is something that I've already tried, but I'm not really sure of how to implement it using the `jquery ui` dialog box. Anyways upvote for you.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, I've added some code to help make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

**Example 1**
Based on the [flag approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501601/87015):

```
var notyStatus = null;
$("#dialog").dialog({
    beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
        // possible values for notyStatus are
        // null: preventDefault and show the warning
        // else: do nothing and let the dialog close
        if (notyStatus === null) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('<p title="Replace me with noty">Close the dialog?</p>').dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () {
                        notyStatus = true;
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Keep Open": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[**Demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ajgG8/7/)

**Example 2**
Remove the `beforeClose` event handler. You can use `.dialog("option", "beforeClose")` to get, set or unset the event handler. The code looks like this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('<p title="Replace me with noty">Close the dialog?</p>').dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $("#dialog")
                        .dialog("option", "beforeClose", null)
                        .dialog("close");
                },
                "Keep Open": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ajgG8/6/)

In both examples, replace the inner jQuery UI confirmation dialog code with noty. It allows you to create action buttons with callbacks so the code will be similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dialog widget's "option" method to change or remove the beforeClose event handler.

So when the user clicks 'yes', you could get the dialog to close by executing:

```
$('#myDialog')
  .dialog('option', 'beforeClose', function() {})
  .dialog('close');
```

Here's a fiddle that shows how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/BrDE7/1/

Jquery UI documentation on the "option" method: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-option

Answer (score 2):

According to the code for the `close` API for Jquery UI dialog, there is no way not to **force** close a dialog without firing events. Ideally there should be an API which just executes the functionality without triggering events. I tried just a way to enable this by replicating the method for now. Best way as an addition to the API itself. So the change is something on the lines of this,

```
// code from existing
if(!forceClose && this._trigger("beforeClose") === false){
    return;
}
// continue with existing
```

Have a fiddle for the same here http://jsfiddle.net/Lj3Nk/1/

Going to submit a feature/pull request to jquery ui now. Will update with details when done. In the mean while, let me know if this helps.

**UPDATE**

Jquery ui ticket - http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9943

Pull request - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/pull/1218